# How to find which library fields are not being filled by users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

Before migrating a 2010 Farm to 2016, I want to create cleaner library so I want to eliminate the fields that stopped being used on 2010.

Is there a tool of PowerShell script I can run to tell me which optional fields do not have value in items made lately?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists or libraries are fairly standardized, You could try exporting a library or list to excel. Then use Excel to filter and sort the data to determine columns with highest number of blanks, etc.
That could help you determine which fields are being ignored the most.

Comment: I have about 100 site collections with the same set of libraries.